# Update EE Maps by Reinos height & redraw on button click

Tags: add-on, google-maps, ee4

I'm in the process of transitioning a site from an older version of Objective HTML Gmaps to EE Maps by Reinos and I'm having trouble with one feature that the older Gmaps (or perhaps the Google Maps API) made quite easy.

When clicking on a "more map" button on the map, the map was redrawn and resized based on the larger height 150px <-> 400px. This was accomplished with:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(placesmap, 'resize');
```

With EE Maps, I'm struggling to make this same behavior happen. If anyone has any experience with this I'm at a loss. I've also given the updateMap [EE Maps API call](https://docs.reinos.nl/maps/#updatemap) a go

```
EE_MAPS.api('', {
  mapID : 'ee_map_1',
  options: {height : '400px'}
});
```

But this likewise doesn't do anything. You can see the behavior on [this page](http://dev.visithampshirecounty.com/places/).

Comment: Rein confirmed to me that the EE maps module does not as of now support the Google Maps API. He will likely change that.

Answer (score 0):

To those in the future that find this question, you can now "refresh" the map with the follow JS:

```
EE_MAPS.api('refresh', {
  mapID : 'ee_map_1', 
});
```

Make sure to change ee_map_1 to whatever your map ID is if you changed it!